# Derivative of a monotonically non-decreasing function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, derivatives, continuity

**The theorem:**
Let $I\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ be an open interval and $f\colon I\to\mathbb{R}$ a monotonically non-decreasing function which is differentiable in a point $x_0\in I$. Then: $f'(x_0)\geq 0$.

**My proof attempt:**
Let $x$ be an arbitrary point in $I$. There are two possible cases:

1. $x\geq x_0$. Here we have $f(x)\geq f(x_0)$ which implies that the difference quotient $\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$ is non-negative.
2. $x<x_0$. In this case $f(x)\leq f(x_0)$ and the same result follows.

Now in any case the derivative $f'(x_0)=\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$ is also non-negative. $\square$

**My problem:**
I have a feeling that the last step is lacking something. And additionaly: I have seen the same theorem elsewhere but with different initial conditions like continuity or differentiability on the whole interval. Is anything else required here?

Comment: That's fine. If $f$ is increasing then $\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0} \ge 0$ for all $x \ne x_0$. What exactly are your doubts about it?

Comment: I thought I should add a reason why it is also true for the limit in particular.